# Нужны ли запятые между неполными предложениями?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, и

Нужны ли запятые перед союзом И между предложениями (в обоих случаях)?

> В ассортименте пена для бритья
>   И стратегический запас лосьонов,
>   С патронами коробки для ружья
>   И несколько подарочных купонов.

Answer (score 1):

Мне думается, что "в ассортименте" нельзя распространять на все однородные подлежащие — как предлагает *Sharon* (то есть компоновать подлежащие попарно).

При таком "раскладе" возникает странный смысл: в ассортименте стратегический (необходимый для определенной цели) запас, в ассортименте коробки с патронами (ружьё-то одно), в ассортименте несколько купонов (*несколько* — не могут быть в ассортименте).
И еще. Если не ставить запятую перед вторым союзом "и", то возникает очередная двусмысленность: с патронами коробки и несколько купонов (купоны — с патронами?).

Считаю, что это неполное предложение, в котором пропущено сказуемое; "в ассортименте" относится только к подлежащему "пена"; союз связывает больше двух однородных членов — ставим перед всеми "и" запятые (заодно избавляемся и от двусмысленностей).

([Есть] В ассортименте пена, и запас, коробки, и несколько купонов.)
Перед предлогом "с" запятая, конечно же, нужна.

*В ассортименте пена для бритья,

И стратегический запас лосьонов,

С патронами коробки для ружья,

И несколько подарочных купонов.*

[Трудные случаи пунктуации. Запятая перед союзом «И»](https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/315-zapyatayaperedsyuzomi.html)

Comment: Вот я и сомневалась между двумя вариантами: либо это однородные члены, соединенные попарно (как предполагает Sharon), либо Ваш вариант с повторяющимся союзом И, соединяющим однородные члены. Но думаю, Ваш вариант логичнее и запятые нужны.

Comment: Зачем запятая перед первым "и"? Если ставим запятую перед "с", то перед вторым "и" уже не нужно.

Comment: Вас сложно понять, _oleedd_. Вы же сами написали в своем ответе: _Перед предлогом "с" запятая не нужна._

Comment: *В ассортименте пена, и запас, коробки, и несколько купонов.* — не могу понять, на каком основании первая и третья запятые? Такое ощущение, что я не знаю какого-то правила. Хочется разобраться.

Comment: *В ассортименте пена, и запас, коробки, и несколько купонов.* — Зачем вы вводите людей в заблуждение? Такая пунктуация противоречит правилам русского языка. Если нет, то объясните, чтобы всем стало понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Наугад берём кого-нибудь из относительно современных поэтом и смотрим строфы.

---

Евтушенко:

> Хотят ли русские войны?
>
> Спросите вы у тишины
>
> над ширью пашен и полей
>
> и у берез и тополей.
>
> Спросите вы у тех солдат,
>
> что под березами лежат,
>
> и пусть вам скажут их сыны,
>
> хотят ли русские войны.

Или Бродский:

> Вижу колонны замерших внуков,
>
> гроб на лафете, лошади круп.
>
> Ветер сюда не доносит мне звуков
>
> русских военных плачущих труб.
>
> Вижу в регалиях убранный труп:
>
> в смерть уезжает пламенный Жуков.

---

Что можно сказать? В общем поэтический синтаксис ничем не отличается от синтаксиса прозаического, да и пунктуация тоже. В вашем примере, если исходить из обычного синтаксиса, запятые перед союзами ненужны.

Answer (score 0):

*В ассортименте пена для бритья*

*И стратегический запас лосьонов,*

*С патронами коробки для ружья*

*И несколько подарочных купонов.*

Это эллиптическое предложение вида "обстоятельство — подлежащее": в ассортименте (что)?

А вот подлежащее — это распространенный однородный ряд, в котором  члены ряда связаны союзом И попарно: *пена и запас, коробки и несколько купонов*.

**Предлог С** к структуре предложения отношения не имеет, это **инверсия**: коробки с патронами для ружья.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

**Что логично?** По-моему, логично прочитать всё стихотворение, а потом делать выводы https://vk.com/wall-19359310_243220

Насколько я понимаю, леди перебирает подарки мужу, которые уже имеются, вот и называет иронично **весь ряд этих подарков *ассортиментом*.**

Comment: Конечно, Sharon, такой смысл тоже может быть. Но тогда автору **надо** было поставить после "в ассортименте" **двоеточие** — одна из двусмысленностей сразу бы исчезла. Но дамоклов меч в кавычках бы все равно остался, и другие пунктуационные вольности — тоже. Например: _Ещё гантели сложенные в ряд - (Отдел закоренелого атлета!)_

Comment: В стихотворении каждое четверостишье вполне самостоятельно, да и точка в конце этого  стоит.  Двоеточие не стоит ставить, предупредительная пауза там ни к чему, ударение сразу падает на члены однородного ряда. Да и двусмысленности никакой  я  не заметила, все вполне корректно (в этой части стиха).

Comment: При такой пунктуации вторая половина уже не относится к ассортименту.

Comment: ...сказал oleedd. Все уважительно замолчали и стали думать: При какой пунктуации? Какая вторая половина? Почему она к этому ассортименту  уже не относится?  И что сделать, чтобы относилась?

Comment: Вы бы лучше в своем ответе записали текст стеми знаками, какие считаете правильными, тогда не надо было бы про предлоги рассказывать. Затем надо определить вид предложения и объяснить запятые. Если уж вы беретесь отвечать, оформляйте ответ по правилам. Забыли, как это делается, совсем расслабились?